# Show Interactive Html elements on top of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a area surrounded by an anchor tag and it should be directed to anchor tag href wherever user clicks on that area. And also that area should contain a textbox and button control which should allow user to type some text and submit. The problem is when I click on the textbox or button it does a redirect to the page given in anchor tag.

```
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
<div style="border:1px solid grey;width:300px;height:100px;">
    <div style="">Title</div>
     <div>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('button clicked');">Click Me!</button>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Please refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTbAN/2/).
I have created a simplified problem here.
However I found a solution for this by giving negative margin-top values. It is working but I am interested in a better solution. Because this solution is not scalable since the button and textbox are not inside the content div.

Each of these sections represent a item in a search result. When a user click on a search item it would navigate to single item page. At the same time users should be able to edit content from search results view by selecting edit option. When they select edit, a textbox and a button to submit should appear.

Comment: As Gareth says, the answer is no. But what exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you describe what your original intention is, rather than talking in terms of what you have made? Then you may be able to get better solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the HTML5 spec says about the [`<a> element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model:
>
> Transparent, but there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

What that means is, an `<a>` element is allowed to contain any elements that its parent is allowed to contain, except for things like `<button>`.

You'll need to find a way to get your `<button>` and `<input>` working outside of the `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<input type="text" name="name" onclick="return false;" />
```

Use this only if you don't want to change your markup.

The best solution is go with the semantics of HTML and style it. This way is not correct as Gareth pointed out.

In the case of your button

```
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick(event);">Click Me!</button>

function buttonClick(e) {
            alert('button clicked');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a onclick for textfield and use stoppropagation method for a event. for ex ,

```
textfield.onclick = function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Another alternate is to use `<div onclick="function()">` instead of `<a>` tag for what you think to achieve